# make the if else statement one liner in python

Tags: python

How can I make the if else statement as below one liner?

```
uly = '50'

if '-' in uly:
     uly = uly.replace('-','S')
else:
     uly = 'N'+uly

print uly
```

My trial:

```
uly = [uly=uly.replace('-','S') if '-' in uly else uly = 'N'+uly]
print uly
```

Comment: Why do you necessarily need a one-liner? Most people will find this a lot more readable.

Comment: Just to shorten my code, if possible.

Comment: You should optimize for readibility, not for short code. There's absolutely nothing wrong with how you're doing it, and I personally strongly prefer the explicit if-else look to the single line version.

Comment: I was a Perl programmer before I learned Python, so when I switched to Python, I had an irrational need to make my Python code as short and clever as possible because that was what is encouraged in Perl. It took a while to get over that, and when I did it actually makes writing code more enjoyable.  If my story matches yours, please consider forgetting all the Perl idioms you have locked away and stop caring about the shortest possible code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will do it:

```
uly = uly.replace('-', 'S') if '-' in uly else 'N' + uly
```

This uses the so-called [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) (similar to an `if` statement except that it's an expression and not a statement).

What you have right now is an attempt at a list comprehension, which is unsuitable since there are no lists involved.

All that aside, I would urge you to rethink optimising for the shortest code. As a general rule, readability should trump compactness.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
uly = '-' in uly and uly.replace('-','S') or 'N'+uly
```

Comment: I'm quite comfortable with this idiom, and often used it in the days before the conditional expression was available, although it does have the drawback that it may not do what you want if the expression following `and` evaluates as false. So I tend towards using the conditional expression these days when I think the use of a one-liner is warranted. OTOH, I _do_ agree that readability trumps saving a few lines of code and the explicit if-else construction tends to be *lot* more readable than the one-liner versions.